# Facebook Thumbnail won't load

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched through a number of similar posts and most seem to be asking how to change their thumbnail...I'm not even getting as far as that.

I have the following meta information in my :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MyWebsite"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="company"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myWebsite.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myWebsite.com/images/logo.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description"
          content="MyWebsite is brilliant."/>
```

When I attempt to paste http://www.MyWebsite.com into a Facebook status update, it is correctly displaying the description, but it is not pulling the image.

I have used the Facebook Debugger/Linter and it is pulling everything correctly...so where is the disjoint? I have tried different browsers and still no thumbnail.

One thing I have noticed is that if I validate my website with W3C it is saying that "property" is not allowed as an attribute. Is this normal?

Are there dimensions for the logo? Mine is roughly 574px by 187px.

Answer (score 1):

Use the debug tool as the administrator of your application (set the app_id OG tags to help with this). If you are the app administrator, the debug tool should reset the cache and pickup the new image when sharing on Facebook.

Comment: No, I don't think that's it. It is not an application I am trying to link. I am simply trying to paste the URL of a website into a Facebook Status update.

Comment: Then you will have to wait for Facebook to update it's cache before the new image is picked up. Facebook caches the tags so it won't show the updated image until cache is updated.